# Replacement for Navigation-based application template in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-template

Xcode 4.2 no longer has the Navigation-based Application template.

What should I use in replacement when starting a project?

Comment: See this anser - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8239664/194544

Answer (score 2):

to get a Table View and a Detail View you should go with the Master-detail template. Although at first you may think about it being iPad-only, the iPhone version builds an application which is similar to the Navigation-based.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it works. Anyway, you should start with a single view application, then add the files from the New-File menu. You should select View. Then click create. It should generate the required files for you.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4.2 you have to use SIngle-View Application Template. it's the same than Navigation-based Application template.

Comment: It's not the same. No "Table View" is implemented and you have to do that manually.

Comment: Actually, the single-view template is even much more better than the Navigation-based since it doesn't oblige me to start my app with a table view screen.

Comment: This doesn't answer pdenlinger's question.

Answer (score 0):

The Single View Application does not set up the nav controller for you either. You have to build it manually.

What I suggest doing, if you can, load an older version of Xcode and create a blank Navigation-Based app. Use it as a reference for your new apps. You'll have to change your class and file names, of course, but I dont see any issue with doing it that way.

Comment: Actually, I just tested using the Master-Detail application and it is remarkably similar to the Navigation-Based template from earlier revisions.