# Cannot find Xcode 4 new project template for navigation controller based app. Any alternative?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I am working on iOS 5. I am not able to find the navigation based application template formerly found in Xcode.

So what can I use instead?

Comment: Similar to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196123/replacement-for-navigation-based-application-template-in-xcode-4-2?lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use **Master-Detail Application** template. Choose **Device Family** from dropdown list as **iPhone**. After creating a project your appDelegate will contain `UINavigationController` instance.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

and

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I read the best way to do it was via a single view based project, but this seems to be more like the old navigation based template. Still think it's strange apple made it so obscure... it was my most used template :P

Answer (score 13):

If you want to start from scratch, start with a **Single View Based** project, then go to the storyboard and select the viewController, go to Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 3):

Use storyboard and drag a view controller into it. Then go Editor>Embed In>Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the *Empty Application* project. Add a UINavigationController.

This article, [Creating a Navigation based iOS 5 iPhone Application using TableViews](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews), will guide you. And this tutorial, [Navigation Controllers and View Controller Hierarchies](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies/).