# How do you make a multi-page app in Xcode for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to Xcode and am having trouble with my single view/view-based application for iPhone.

I have 2 buttons on the view and I need simple beginner instructions on how to make 1 button go to a different page and have a back button and have the other button on that view do the same as the first button.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: I know the post is outdated, but for everybody still wondering how to do this: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_mvc

Comment: @a.scarlett That's a Microsoft Xamarin guide, note that this post is tagged xcode.

Comment: @jrh my bad, but my answer is 8 years old so feel free to provide something more updated :)

Answer (score 2):

You are likely looking for a UINavigationController. There are many good tutorials for getting started with that.

This has links to some sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It looks like the link is now dead, but I think [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller?language=objc) covers the same thing, though unfortunately it does not seem to have much in the way of sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You need navigation based app. Take a look at here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html to understand what a navigation based app and how that works with uitableview.

Comment: Sadly, they took the navigation-based application template out of the latest versions of Xcode.

Comment: Yea, that's pretty sad. Luckily it is not too complicated to do it from the scratch. Plus it would be easy to download a navigation based app and modify it. I agree with you, and I think it is a stupid idea to take that template away. But you know Apple, they always do what they want...

Comment: But how do I connect the UINavigationController to my buttons which later leads to pages with both UINavigationController and UITableView?

Comment: The easiest way would be using - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and do [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]; And that's the pretty standard way of doing it. I know you wanna put buttons but you can use the cell itself as a button.

Comment: And if you do want to make the buttons looks like not in a UITableView, there are probably different ways of doing it. Here is the way I done before: Make a UITableView to contain only one section and one row, then it will looks like a button and you could handle your navigation job in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.

Comment: It looks like the link in this post is now dead, I'm having trouble finding an exact replacement, but [Replacement for Navigation-based application template in Xcode 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8196123/4975230) and maybe [Table Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views?language=objc) are relevant?